# How to remove the promise from loadChildren in Angular 15 importing a module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, angular-migration

I am upgrading my application from Angular 14 to Angular 15 and I faced some problems when trying to remove the promise in my loadChildren call.

```
{
    path: 'julio-app',
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./modules/julioApp/julioApp.module').then(
            (m) => m.JulioAppModule
        ),
},
```

After removing it the promise call like this:

```
{
    path: 'julio-app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/julioApp/julioApp.module'),
},
```

I received the following error:

**"Cannot find module './modules/julioApp/julioApp.module' or its corresponding type declarations."**

Do you guys have faced this error before while upgrading to Angular 15? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to remove the promise? you have to return a module